# SQL Server update trigger not firing on all changes

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-update

This is for a intranet app that's been running fine for years.  Recently users passwords have been randomly changing so I created an update trigger and a history table to try and track it down.

The table is AspNetUsers and this is my trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AspNetUsersUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO AspNetUsersHistory ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [PasswordHash], [SecurityStamp],..., LastUpdated)
    SELECT *,getdate()
    FROM deleted

END
```

One uses has had to reset his password that last 2 mornings so I went to the history table to see what's up.

```
SELECT a.Id
    ,a.LastName
    ,a.PasswordHash NewPassword
    ,h.passwordHash OldPassword
    ,h.lastUpdated 
FROM AspNetUsersHistory h
    INNER JOIN AspNetUsers a on h.Id = a.Id
WHERE a.Id = 3028
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC
```

returns:

```
Id      LastName    NewPassword         OldPassword lastUpdated
3028    Martin      CorrectPassword     WrongXXX    2022-02-15 08:54:17.5400000 +00:00
3028    Martin      CorrectPassword     WrongYYY    2022-02-15 08:36:53.7930000 +00:00
3028    Martin      CorrectPassword     WrongQQQ    2022-02-14 10:22:44.9000000 +00:00
3028    Martin      CorrectPassword     WrongZZZ    2022-02-14 08:32:10.9930000 +00:00
```

I used aliases for the New/Old password to make it more readable here.  Every time he resets his password it records it to my history table.  But at some point on 2/15 is password changed from CorrectPassword to WrongXXX and that wasn't recorded in my history table.  The same thing happened on 2/14 as well.

Comment: You might consider using *system versioning* for your table instead.

Comment: Made the changes for versioning and dropped my trigger.  I'll give it some time now to capture the changes.  Thanks